# how to stop wrinkles on face when sleeping on stomach

Tags: sleep

How to stop wrinkles on face when sleeping on stomach ? or Is this a myth that we get wrinkles if we sleep on stomach ?

Comment: Myth. The "wrinkles" are just indentations in the skin where it's been pressed against the pillow. They disappear within minutes after awakening.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks, you can post it as an answer.....